# CPAN Authen Simple LDAP HTTP Error

Tags: perl, apache

I have installed LDAP.pm using CPAN with:

```
install Authen::Simple::LDAP
```

I try to load the module in Apache with:

```
PerlLoadModule Authen::Simple::LDAP
```

Whenever I try to start the server, I get an error that says:

```
Syntax error on line 285 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
Attempt to reload Authen/Simple/LDAP.pm aborted.\nCompilation failed in require at (eval 12) line 3.\n
```

Line 285 of my httpd configuration file:

```
PerlLoadModule Authen::Simple::LDAP
```

Is there something wrong with the installation of the LDAP perl module?  Is there another way I can install this module?  Am I missing any other modules, and how do I know which ones?

Additional information: running

```
perl -MAuthen::Simple::LDAP -e ''
```

Returns:

```
Bareword "Params::Validate::SCALAR" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at /usr/local/share/perl5/Authen/Simple/Adapter.pm line 42.
Bareword "Params::Validate::SCALAR" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at /usr/local/share/perl5/Authen/Simple/Adapter.pm line 42.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 2) line 3.
...propagated at /usr/share/perl5/base.pm line 94.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl5/Authen/Simple/LDAP.pm line 5.
Compilation failed in require.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborte
```

Comment: As shown in my edit: line 285 is the place where I load the module.

Comment: Sorry @nuclearpenguin. I'm giving myself a time out.

Comment: What does running `perl -MAuthen::Simple::LDAP -e ''` say?